# .Net Core returning a list of 2 different objects with multiple properties connected to each other

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having trouble with returning a list of objects that are inside of a class. Those objects are different, one is a list of `User` objects, which contains a few properties and the other is a `KanbanTask` which has its own properties.

`User` and `KanbanTask` are connected in the database with a many-to-many relationship. I want to return an list of all `KanbanTasks` with their properties and additional list of users connected to this task. I am using repository pattern and both repository and controller work fine, the problem is in service class. Visual Studio doesn't show any errors, but when testing in swagger it doesn't work and shows errors.

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<TaskWithUserListDTO> GetAllUsersPerTask()
{
    var list = await _taskrepo.GetAll(y => y.Id);
    var userTaskList = await _usertaskrepo.GetAll(x => x.User, y => y.KanbanTask);

    List<TaskWithUserDTO> newList = new List<TaskWithUserDTO>();

    foreach (KanbanTask task in list)
    {
        var ifHasUser = await _usertaskrepo.GetSingleEntity(x => x.KanbanTaskId == task.Id);

        if (ifHasUser == null)
        {
            newList.Add(new TaskWithUserDTO
                            {
                                KanbanTask = task,
                                UserList = new List<User>()
                            });
        }
        else
        {
            List<User> finalList = new List<User>();

            foreach (UserTask userTask in userTaskList)
            {
                if (userTask.KanbanTaskId == task.Id)
                {
                    var user = await _repo.GetSingleEntity(x => x.Id == userTask.UserId);
                    finalList.Add(user);
                }
            }

            newList.Add(new TaskWithUserDTO
                            {
                                 KanbanTask = task,
                                 UserList = finalList
                            });
        }
    }

    var userList = new TaskWithUserListDTO() { TaskWithUserList = newList };
    return userList;
}
```

Here are the 2 models I use for this

```
namespace Kanban.Model.Models.Response
{
    public class TaskWithUserDTO
    {
        public KanbanTask KanbanTask { get; set; }
        public List<User> UserList { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskWithUserListDTO
    {
        public List<TaskWithUserDTO> TaskWithUserList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

User and KanbanTask models (Entity is a model with only Id):

```
public class User : Entity
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

public class KanbanTask : Entity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required] 
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int ProgressStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Class that connects those models

```
public class UserTask : Entity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int KanbanTaskId { get; set; }
    public KanbanTask KanbanTask { get; set; }
}
```

End result should look like this (if there is more than 1 user assigned to task then there would be multiple users shown in a list, if there is none, then there would be an empty list

```
"List": [
{
"kanbanTask": 
        {
          "title": "string",
          "description": "string",
          "status": "string",
          "progressStatus": 2,
          "id": 1
},
"userList" :
    {
    "name": "string",
        "surname": "string",
        "id": 1
}]
```

Error from swagger:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable`2.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Kanban.Repository.Repository`1.GetAll(Expression`1[] includes) in C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\Projekt Kanban\Projekt Kanban\Kanban.Repository\Repository.cs:line 56
   at Kanban.Service.UserService.GetAllUsersPerTask() in C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\Projekt Kanban\Projekt Kanban\Kanban.Services\UserService.cs:line 216
   at Projekt_Kanban.Controllers.UserController.GetAllUsersPerTask() in C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\Projekt Kanban\Projekt Kanban\Projekt Kanban\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 97
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,uk-UA;q=0.6,uk;q=0.5,ru;q=0.4,de;q=0.3
Connection: close
Host: localhost:44346
Referer: https://localhost:44346/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Comment: Can I guess that `GetSingleEntity` is actually your custom method inside your repo?

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan Yes, it returns a single entity of the repository type you are using. If you use _repo.GetSingleEntity then you will get an User object.
Here is how it look like
 public async Task<T> GetSingleEntity(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
        {
            var entity = await _dbSet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(func);
            return entity;
        }

Comment: Ok, but that's a bit strange because the error is obviously connected with the `Include` method used somewhere in your code, I guess you wrote something like `Include(p => p.KanbanTask.Title)` instead of just `Include(p=>p.KanbanTask)`

Comment: Only Include method that I can find is in the GetAll function
| public async Task<List<T>> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
            foreach (var include in includes)
            {
                query = query.Include(include);
            }
            var list = await query.ToListAsync();
            return list;
        }

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan I found what caused the bug, it was this line of code
 var list = await _taskrepo.GetAll(y => y.Id);
Basically i had to delete the lamda expression in GetAll method. 
Thank you so much for help, without you I wouldnt have known where to look for this bug :)